# How to keep a Java program secure from hacking

Tags: java, android, security

I created a Java programm which works on the serverside to communicate with an Android-App over `Sockets`. Now I want to check wether it is secure to hacking. I also asked in the Security.SE forum but this is programming related. So what do I need to look for in my Java-program to make it heavy to be exploided?

Comment: To be honest there is **NO** way to keep any programs(any language) secure from hacking. Obfuscation is a good way but it doesn't make it completely secure.

Comment: Look at your java code, if it has bugs inside, then you are probably a subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to check would be the server it's running on. You can cerainly checkout the https://www.owasp.org/ website. It is always a good source of security threats. Then there are a lot of pentesting tools https://www.kali.org/ has many of them built in. 
But the most important might be how you've designed your API, I mean you're not very specific about what you need to know but some rules that will certainly apply:

- secure the communication
- make sure id theft is as hard as possible
- never store userpasswords yourself(use a tokenbased system like oauth)

Answer (score 0):

Obfuscation via proguard makes the program harder to reverse engineer.

Comment: Using proguard still make the apps being cracked. Especially for in-app purchase.

Answer (score 0):

**Obfuscation combined with Ahead-Of-Time Compilation**

1) Obfuscate names and encrypt strings using the tools not relying on the application being delivered in bytecode form. Make sure to disable control/data flow obfuscations.

2) Compile the obfuscated application down to optimized native code.

see link 
http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html